# MySQL query to sum from similar view into one resultant view

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a project where I came across this problem. The scenario is that I have 30 views indicating the count of status of each financial year. So my requirement is to have a resultant view which consist of sum of entire 30 view.Hope my problem is clear Thank you in advance.

For Example
View 1:

[image]

View 2:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Post the code here, as code, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to `UNION ALL` all 30 views into a single "table expression", and then select from it grouping by the financial year, as in:

```
select financial_year,
    sum(status_1) as status_1,
    sum(status_0) as status_0,
    sum(status_2) as status_2,
    sum(status_3) as status_3,
    sum(status_4) as status_4
  from (
  select financial_year, status_1, status_0, status_2, status_3, status_4,
      totals from view1
  union all
  select financial_year, status_1, status_0, status_2, status_3, status_4,
      totals from view2
  union all
  select financial_year, status_1, status_0, status_2, status_3, status_4,
      totals from view3
  union all
  ... -- add view4 to view30 here
  ) x
  group by financial_year;
```